# 2 webcam feed doesn't work opencv

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I'm using ubuntu 13.10 along with opencv 2.4.9 with python 2.7.
I have written the following code but it seems to fails on runtime.

```
  import cv2
  c1=cv2.VideoCapture(2) #camera id
  c2=cv2.VideoCapture(1) #camera id
  while(True):
      ret,frame = c1.read()
      ret,frame2 = c2.read()
      frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,0)
      frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,0)
      cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
      cv2.imshow('frame2',frame2)
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

  c1.release()
  c2.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But on running this in Ubuntu i get the following error :

```
  VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
  libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
  VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
  OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file 
    /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.5+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3358

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bini/KV/IP_Proj/webcam basics opencv.py", line 8, in <module>
  frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2,0)  
 cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.5+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3358: error:       
 (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

The same code used to work fine on windows.
Can someone help me please as to why is this occuring..??? i have on idea.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For linux,if you're using 1 camera , at first you must change your camera id to 0 , but it seems that you want use 2 camera , **this is because the resolution, framerate and protocol used by your cameras overloads the USB connection** so read [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4909/using-2-webcams-simultaneously/?answer=7228#post-id-7228) link! also this is a base code for connect and use linux webcam:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#set the width and height, and UNSUCCESSFULLY set the exposure time
cap.set(3,1080)
cap.set(4,1024)
cap.set(15, 0.1)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("input",img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

Comment: Now that both my cameras are working , in another code(which is correct) i am getting this error:

     
`HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: index 1 is not correct!`
`Warning: unable to open video source:  1`
`Warning: unable to open video source:  synth`

How to fix this error..??

Comment: is 1 , your camera id ? if its so i think it must be 0 or 3 or ...  t access its id by `lsusb` command .

Comment: yup.1 is my camera id.cause the code for a single webcam using opencv run with camera id=1 for my external webcam

Comment: so did you try other id's ? and read the link that i put in answer

Comment: id's are 1 and 2 only.They've worked on a simpler code for two camera which just display's the feed.But somehow in all other codes (even in the sample codes by opencv) it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

One (or both) of your cameras isn't initializing correctly.  I just ran your code on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04) and both frames come up showing live views from my two connected cameras.  Can you view both cameras in [cheese](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/cheese/) or [guvcview](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/)?

I do get a bunch of these messages:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

errors but neither of these:

```
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Hi @abarry, I am having same problem of "libv4l2: error turning on stream: Invalid argument VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument" and cheese is giving error "There was an error playing video from the webcam". Do you have any solution?

Comment: Sounds like you webcam drivers aren't working.  You might want to search for your particular camera and see what's wrong (perhaps dmesg can provide hints?) OpenCV has little chance of working if you can't get the camera online at all.